# Remove Subversion sourcecontrol from a project (Visual Studio/TortoiseSVN)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you remove Subversion control for a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154853/how-do-you-remove-subversion-control-for-a-folder)

I am implementing the use of Subversion as a source control tool for my projects, but I made some mistakes when determining what structure to use. So I added version control to some folders (projects), that I would like to undo.

How do I do that? Do I have to copy the folder, delete the original and add source control to the new one?

I use TortoiseSVN and [Visual Studio 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2008).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just remove the .svn folders in the folder and all its subfolders.

An easier way to do this would be to Export the folder using TortoiseSVN.

Comment: This is a good answer, but be careful of using this outside the context of this answer.  Deleting .svn folders is a good way to corrupt your working copy (or at least a section of it).

Comment: Also, don't forget to add the files and folders you're removing from SVN to SVN ignore.

Comment: first: set show hidden files and folders

Comment: Where is this .svn folder? I don't see one in my project folder.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the previous comments:

There is a really neat way to export using TortoiseSVN. If you **right click** and drag/drop your SVN folder, when you release the mouse button you will be prompted by a menu including these entries

```
SVN Export to here
SVN Export all to here
```

The latter also copies files not placed under SVN control.

This right click trick can also be used for dragging files and folders around within a repository (simultaneously with editing the working copy), to achieve moves and copies that are otherwise tricky.

Answer (score 3):

Can Berk Güder is correct, but in my experience with SVN (not always very pleasurable), I'd probably add that you would probably want to check your SVN Repository to make sure there aren't any orphans hanging around in there that would be unreconcilable when you re-commit.

And beware of TortoiseSVN, it is not always correct with its status. Probably best to run a Clean post integration.

Also, have a look at VisualSVN. It overcomes DLLs accidentally getting in your source control and works very well with Visual Studio 2008. I use it and it auto-adds things beautifully.

Comment: Thanks. I am actually using ankhsvn, and I think it does the same as VisualSVN - but free - from what I have read anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use switch the solution from Visual Studio. It works wonders.