# Subversion: how to remove all .svn files recursively?

Tags: windows, svn, version-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you remove Subversion control for a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154853/how-do-you-remove-subversion-control-for-a-folder)

Is there such a tool?

I'm being bothered by this issue now again...

Comment: You'll like Subversion 1.7. There's only one `.svn` folder and it resides at the root of the working copy.

Answer (score 20):

```
find . -name .svn -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Just noticed windows tag, so that probably won't help unless you use cygwin.

Comment: Can you elaborate what `{} \;` means here?

Comment: Execute the command rm -rf, which will delete a directory, on every result of the find command.

Answer (score 7):

List them:

```
find . -type f -name .svn
```

Delete them

```
find . -type f -name .svn -delete
```

And if they're actually directories, not files

```
find . -type d -name .svn -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Is this going to work on windows ? *(see the `windows` tag ;-) )*

Comment: @Pascal: wut? doesn't everybody use cygwin?!

Comment: I'd rather prefer everybody *(or at least every developers)* use *(a real)* Linux ^^

Comment: Can you elaborate what `{} \;` means here?

Comment: `-exec command ;` is the syntax for making find execute something. Since the shell would otherwise gobble the `;` I quote it, `\;`. The `{}` is replaced with the file/dir find is currently processing.

Answer (score 5):

now here it is.
Go to your project root directory and use this terminal command:

```
find . -name ".svn" -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is built-in to svn using `svn export`. This can operate in two modes, one which downloads and places a fresh copy of the server content in a new local folder, and the other which takes an existing local folder and creates a new local folder.

Example:
`svn export c:\MyCheckout c:\MyCheckout2`

After executing the above, `c:\MyCheckout2` will contain your checkout but without any `.svn` folders.

You can execute `svn help export` to see more instructions.