# how to break SVN Link of project?

Tags: svn, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu and want to know Is there any other procedure or command to break SVN link of the particular project other than going inside the project and delete each .svn folder of each subfolders in the project.

This method is very time consuming is they are less time consuming method ?

Comment: Possible duplicate [How do you remove Subversion control for a folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154853/how-do-you-remove-subversion-control-for-a-folder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `export` utility for `svn`

```
svn export /path_of_your_working_copy /path_to_plain_copy
```

And then just delete the old working copy.

For Windows Environment using TortoiseSVN this can be done

```
TortoiseSVN > export...
```