# How to remove remote git urls from xcode?

Tags: xcode, git, macos

I have created a git repository but have deleted the repository, so there is nothing to clone from that repository, which means I want to remove these URLs.

How do I remove git remote URLs from `XCode > SourceControl > Checkout`?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXK6W.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your terminal hit below command to clear the xcode preferences

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

Haven't tested, may be this may help you.

Comment: Not working: Domain (com.apple.dt.Xcode) not found.
Defaults have not been changed.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you can find a `.xcheckouts` file which would include those urls for you to remove.
See "[xcode remove repository from project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21608689/6309)".
As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18340453/6309), an `.xccheckout` file contains metadata about what repositories are used in a workspace.

In latest versions of XCode (7), check for a xcode preference file in `/Library/Preferences` (as [in this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/28782))

Comment: i cant find .xcheckouts file in the repo.also the urls of other repo are also visible which has no link with current repo.it seems the urls are stored somewhere globally.

Comment: @Hardyyy I agree. Did you follow http://stackoverflow.com/a/21608689/6309 and right-click on the `project.xcworkspace` file, and select "Show Package Contents" to seek `xcshareddata`?

Comment: yeah found xcshareddata but no .xcheckouts

Comment: @Hardyyy I have edited the answer: do you have XCode 7?

Comment: @Hardyyy Then close XCode, try and remove an xcode preference file in /Library/Preferences and restart XCode, to see if that  makes any difference.

Comment: its seems to be bug.no solution :(

Comment: @Hardyyy I agree, any thread I have seen involving XCode 7 all mention that issue as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

In xCode 11.6 you can open your project, locate the repository tab on the left margin.  Identify the remote connection that you want to delete.  Look at the description in the right tab under it's repository tab and verify that it is the correct remote URL for deletion.  Right click on the repository and delete the repository.[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Xcode -> File -> Add Packages

[image]

2. Recently Used -> Right Click -> Remove.

[image]