# Xcode Showing Homebrew Repository

Tags: xcode, repository, homebrew

I installed a library using homebrew and am using it in my Xcode project. I added my project to Git, and now in the Repository tab I can see 2 entries, mine and homebrew's, and I am not able to delete the homebrew repository.
[image: repository tab in xcode]

Also when I do git branch and remote in the terminal, I only see mine.
[image: git branch and remote]

Why was homebrew repository added and how can I remove it?

Comment: Git itself isn't involved here (except in that it is Git repos that Xcode is keeping track of, but Xcode could keep track of other kinds of repositories too). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36617471/1256452) and its links.

Comment: @torek In the Accounts tab in the preferences I only have my Apple Id and my Github account linked. I also checked the other posts, they all point to a file of `.xcheckouts` or `.xccheckout` which I don't have any of them.

Comment: What about the Library/Preferences files (both system and personal) that [VonC mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36099373/1256452)?

Comment: @torek Yes i also checked the Library/Preferences file I even did `grep` to check if any file there may contain `homebrew` but nothing came back.

Answer (score 0):

Is your project linked to libraries installed by Homebrew? Search for "homebrew" in the `Header Search Paths` and `Library Search Paths` of your targets in Xcode.