# Xcode 7 - Remove source control from project

Tags: git, version-control, xcode7

In order to clean up my git repositories I need to remove the source control from some of my projects.

How can I remove the source control from a project in Xcode 7

I tried the steps on this thread but there is no .xccheckout file to delete.

[xcode remove repository from project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855849/xcode-remove-repository-from-project)

Comment: This answer helped me out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198514/xcode-5-remove-source-control-for-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just disable 'Source Control' in the 'Preferences'

- Open Preferences: Menu 'Xcode/Preferences...'
- In the 'Preferences' dialog select the 'Source Control' pane
- Deselect "Enable Source Control"

Done!

Comment: All that seems to do is temporarily disable source control. When you select "Enable Source Control" again, the project is still under source control.