# How to remove git from xcode project?

Tags: xcode, git

Having configured source control within my Xcode project and linked it to a Git repository hosted on my GitHub profile, I now seek to entirely remove this repository from my project. It's crucial to ensure the safety of all project data, given its significant importance and the extensive development effort invested.

Despite exploring different solutions, including the one outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855849/xcode-remove-repository-from-project), I encountered a roadblock at step 4 as depicted in the provided screenshot.

[image]

It's imperative that any solution ensures the integrity and preservation of my project data throughout the removal process. Could you kindly provide guidance or an alternative method to accomplish this task effectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quit Xcode. Open your project folder in the Finder. Type Shift-Command-Period to reveal invisibles (if they are not already revealed). Find the `.git` folder (note initial dot, which is what makes it invisible). Throw that folder in the trash.

Comment: Thanks, I have made a backup of my project and then deleted .git from my project and initialise it with the required repo and all my issues are now resolved.