# To get a project copy without svn files, Error in SVN export

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

How can I checkout my svn repository without .svn files? I have tried svn export but I am getting an error showing I need to do a clean up process. I tried again after doing the clean up process, but the same error is showing again and again.

Please help.

Comment: Are you checking out to an empty folder?
Anyway if you want to copy a folder but exclude the ".svn" folders you can use robocopy from a command line:
    robocopyc:\sourcefolder d:\destinationfolder ¤.¤ /xd .svn /e

(Replace ¤ with asterisk/star/multiply symbol as StackOverflow removes this symbol from comments)
The /xd is "exclude directory" and will skip all folders with the name ".svn".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you remove Subversion control for a folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154853/how-do-you-remove-subversion-control-for-a-folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use up-to-date Subversion client. You say "without .svn files" in plural, therefore I can guess that you use Subversion 1.6 or older client which working copy contains multiple .svn directories at the root of every directory. Beginning with Subversion 1.7, there is only on .svn directory at the root of the working copy.

If you want to get an export from a repository, use [`svn export`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) command. As a result, you will simply download repository contents without getting a working copy.

Comment: Yes my svn version is 1.6. Did updating the existing svn cause any error on my project?

Comment: Nope, it should not. However, after upgrading to Subversion 1.9, you should run `svn upgrade` against your local working copies to make them compatible with the latest version.